# Is the dartlang plugin for Atom editor compatible with the dart-tools plugin?

Tags: dart, atom-editor

I am writing dart code, using the [dartlang](https://atom.io/packages/dartlang) plugin, and also want to use stagehand templates that are a part of [dart-tools](https://atom.io/packages/dart-tools).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use the dart-tools and dartlang atom plugins together as there's a fair amount of overlap. I'd recommend running stagehand from the command line for now until dartlang supports stagehand directly.